# Xpath and XmlNameSpace

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, namespaces

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FileHeader 
  xmlns="urn:schemas-ncr-com:ECPIX:CXF:FileStructure:020001" 
  VersionNumber="020001" 
  TestFileIndicator="P" 
  CreationDate="13012009" 
  CreationTime="172852" 
  FileID="0000000001"
>
  <Item 
    ItemSeqNo="09011340010009" 
    PayorBankRoutNo="00704524" 
    Amount="398000" 
    AccountNo="000003850010205" 
    SerialNo="000512" 
    TransCode="03"
    PresentingBankRoutNo="00400019" 
    PresentmentDate="13012009" 
    CycleNo="01" 
    NumOfImageViews="2" 
    ClearingType="01" 
    DocType="D" 
    CurrencyInd="LYD" 
    IQAIgnoreInd="0" 
    CashValueInd="1" 
    TruncatingRTNo="00405117" 
    SpecialHandling="00" 
    RepresentmentCnt="0" 
    MICRRepairFlags="000000"
  >
    <AddendA 
      BOFDRoutNo="00400019" 
      BOFDBusDate="13012009" 
      DepositorAcct="0000534983"
    />
    <ImageViewDetail ...
```

And I need to reach the element "ImageViewDetail" using Select(xpath_expression) method of XmlDocument .NET class.

The following code is not working

```
xmlDocument.Select("//Item/AddendA/ImageViewDetail");
```

unless I remove

```
xmlns="urn:schemas-ncr-com:ECPIX:CXF:FileStructure:020001"
```

from "FileHeader" tag

What is the correct way to deal with namespace here?

Thank you,

Comment: I formatted your XML for you so there's no horizontal scrolling. How I hate horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @Welbog - to be honest, I preferred the original; now I have vertical scrolling instead ;-p But either will suffice...

Comment: @ala - btw, the ImageViewDetail doesn't look to be inside the AddendA, so /AddendA/ImageViewDetail won't work anyway...

Comment: @Gravell, u r right. my error. the correct xpath is //x:Item/x:ImageViewDetail.

Thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With an `XmlNamespaceManager` and an alias in the xpath:

```
    XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    mgr.AddNamespace("x", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
    foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes(
          "//x:Item/x:AddendA/x:ImageViewDetail", mgr))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to execute original xpath, without adding aliases into it ?

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.vijaymukhi.com/documents/books/csclasses/chap7.htm you may find something that can help.